# Convert Python dictionary to nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question concerning python dictionaries and nested dictionaries. If I had a dictionary like so:

```
data = {'abc': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'def': ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']}
```

Could I somehow convert the lists inside this dictionary to also be dictionaries?
So that the output would be like:

```
data = {'abc': {'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}, 'def': {'ddd', 'eee', 'fff'}}
```

I'm new to Python and just trying to understand nested dictionaries and how they work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Those are sets, not dictionaries.

Comment: dictionaries need to have a key, Or else that syntax will be a `set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for a dict containing dicts would be

```
data = {
    'abc': {'aaa':1, 'bbb':2, 'ccc':42}, 
    'def': {'ddd':45, 'eee':"Monty", 'fff':None}, # this trailing comma is Pythonic
    }
```

What is in the question as asked is a dict containing sets, which is completely valid and useful.

You would use a dict containing sets (as opposed to lists) if your principal aim was to determine presence or absence, as in `if 'aaa' in data['abc']:` and specifically not to associate any values with the inner keys. (Before sets were added to Python, programmers used dicts with all values set to something arbitrary and irrelevant like `1` or `None`)

You would use a dict containing dicts if you want to be able to store values accessed by an outer and an inner key, as in `data['aaa']['ddd'] = "I'm new here"`, and you can of course still test `if 'ddd' in data['aaa']:`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dictionary of sets then just use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{key:set(value) for key,value in data.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'abc': {'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}, 'def': {'ddd', 'eee', 'fff'}}
```

is invalid python dictionary. Python dictionaries are in form of key:value pairs

What you currently have in your dictionary above is a **dictionary of sets** instead of dictionary of dictionaries.

What you could do is to add some 'dummy' keys to convert from list to dictionary.
For example the following code:

```
data = {'abc': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'def': ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']}
dict2 = {}

i = 0
for key, value in data.items():
    dict2[key] = {}
    for element in value:
        dict2[key][i] = element
        i += 1
    i = 0

print dict2
```

will give you the following output (which is a nested dictionary):

```
{'abc': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'bbb', 2: 'ccc'}, 'def': {0: 'ddd', 1: 'eee', 2: 'fff'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this task using `set`:

```
data = {'abc': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'def': ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']}

b = {}
for key, value in data.items(): 
  b[key] = set(value)

print(b)
```

Output:

```
{'abc': {'ccc', 'bbb', 'aaa'}, 'def': {'fff', 'ddd', 'eee'}}
```